# Declaring an Auto Function is causing an undefined error

Tags: c++, function, auto

So I tried using an auto function for a Reader file and when I declare it in its own .cpp file and .h file I receive the error:

> 'Reader': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined

But the function works perfectly in the .cpp file where main function is declared.

Reader.cpp

```
auto Reader(std::string Location, int Value)
{
    //Code - I removed the code for simplicity sake
    return 1;
}
```

Reader.h

```
auto Reader(std::string Location, int Value);
```

This is how its called in the main function:

```
    int Renderer = Reader("Engine.Setup", Test);
```

Comment: in `main` all the compiler should have access to is the `auto Reader(std::string Location, int Value);` declaration in the header which provides no useful information on what `Reader` returns. You may need a trailing return type here. Or just return `int`

Comment: That's why I commented //Code where my code is, but for simplicity sake I put return 1;

Comment: I think you miss my point. Reader.cpp knows what `Reader` returns. Reader.h does not, so `main` won't know either unless you include Reader.cpp to get the full definition. But including a cpp file is an act so foul that your family name will be cursed forever by programmers who have to deal with the aftermath.

Comment: I won't use auto then at this point

Comment: @user12826193 There is nothing wrong with using `auto` in general, when it is used *correctly*. But this example is not a correct use of `auto`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the error because, when compiling `main.cpp`, the compiler cannot see the inferred return type of `Reader()` in `reader.cpp` so it doesn't know what it is.

Solution: declare the return type of `Reader()` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hypothetical main.cpp

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <Reader.h>

int main ()
{
    int Renderer = Reader("Engine.Setup", Test);
}
```

After the preprocessor deals with the `include` statements it will look like

```cpp
// contents of string. Goes on for miles so I won't reproduce it here.
auto Reader(std::string Location, int Value);

int main ()
{
    int Renderer = Reader("Engine.Setup", Test);
}
```

Nowhere in this file is the return type of `Reader` clear, so you have to give it a hint. Reader.cpp knows what the return type is because it can infer it from the definition of the function, but Reader.cpp is a different [Translation Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) and will be compiled separately. Main.cpp is left completely unaware that anyone knows the return type, and what main.cpp doesn't know, the compiler doesn't know and an error is reported.

The path of least resistance is to explicitly state

```
int Reader(std::string Location, int Value);
```

in Reader.h. You can also provide the hint with a trailing return type.

```
auto Reader(std::string Location, int Value)-> int;
```